# How to get DHCP info from DHCP Client to DHCP Server

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcpd, dhclient

I have a firewall with an Internet-facing ethernet, and a home LAN facing ethernet. The Internet-facing interface acquires DNS server ip addresses from the ISP's DHCP server. I would like to propagate that information on a timely basis when the ISP changes it. I'm not sure if the ISC DHCP server & client I'm using has a way to accommodate this; I can't see any reference to it in their docs. 
My best hunch is that a `/etc/dhclient-script/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/` script  can read the info whenever the firewall's own lease renews. But how to inject it into the data that the DHCP server uses? I can't imagine I'm the first person to want this, but I can't find any prior work on web-land. 
This is all on the ISC DHCP from Debian 8 repositories. I have a use-case  for a similar application, that would propagate local DHCP option parameters in a similar way, if there is one.

Comment: What's your firewall package? Also, what is 'ISC'?

Comment: A lot of people just use `dnsmasq` for this sort of thing, instead of ISC DHCPd.  It gets the list of DNS servers from `/etc/resolv.conf` (which dhclient normally rewrites) and regularly polls that file.  Then your downsteam clients use your server as their DNS server.

Comment: @Seamus ISC is www.isc.org - "Internet Systems Consortium".  They provide BIND and DHCP opensource tools.   I think their DHCP server was one of the first around.

Comment: And you're using *that* DHCP server?

Comment: If I understood correctly you need to know what are the options your DHCP client requesting and ISP's DHCP server sends to it. you have to check particular DHCP client debug messages or firewall Syslog. And in the config file you can find the options it ask from ISP DHCP server

Comment: Seamus: the firewall is just using netfilter rules on the Linux host. I don't think that is actually a relevant part of the equation, though.

Comment: Stephan: I think I see the dnsmasq function as a solution to this particular use case, and I'll explore that. I won't solve any more general case of passing parameters received by the DHCP client and bridging it over to the DHCP server on the same host, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes,  the DHCP server and client are both ISC products. I've used those both before, and they're supported by Debian as packages in the Debian repos. I'm familiar with how they work, and use them both widely already, but if there's a solution using other tools, I would be okay with trying them.

Comment: gripen: DHCP clients request options, but also receive optional data at the discretion of the DHCP server. The LAN-side DHCP server needs to propagate those options from the WAN-side client, so that they will be seen by the LAN hosts when their leases renew. DNS server addresses are a specific case. The options supported by the 'local options' feature of the DHCP protocol (supported by ISC DHCP client & server) are the more general case I'd like to try to solve.